# Convert to DATE T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a field with date in the format *dd.mm.yyyy* E.x. *29.05.2016*. I want to SELECT it as DATE but I get an error when I try the following:

```
CAST([PublishedDate] AS DATE) AS PublishedOn
```

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) I tried the following:

```
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [PublishedDate], 126)  AS PublishedDate
```

But it doesn't change the format.
How do I SELECT to have it in YYYY-MM-DD format.

EDIT: I have 3 different date fields with all three having different formats: dd.mm.yyyy | yyyy-mm-dd | yyyy/mm/dd. I want to select all of them with the same format. Since I use this query to build reports, right now I have dates in different formats. Doing the following:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [PublishedDate], 104) AS PublishedOn
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [ValidFromDate], 104)  AS ValidFrom
```

Gives me the following [image: output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the right [format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql), in your case it would be:

```
CONVERT(date, [PublishedDate], 104)  AS PublishedDate
```

Also, once it's in a `date`, `datetime` or other date datatype, it doesn't have a format at all.

**edit**: Once you have your values in a `date` datatype, of course you can recast to a `varchar` to get the visual representation of the date you need.

**edit2**: If you want a `date` datatype, you should convert to date: `CONVERT(DATE, [your column], [your format])`.
If you want a `nvarchar` datatype, you should convert to nvarchar: `CONVERT(nvarchar(x), [your column], [your format])`.

You have an `nvarchar` that you want to display in a certain format, so you should first convert to date, then back to `varchar` (I doubt you need unicode):

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(date, [PublishedDate], 104), 126)
```

The `104` you have to change for columns that are currently in a different format.

The best solution by far, is to change the datatypes to `date`. That is a bit of work, but definitely worthwhile.

Comment: That's because your local settings tell sql-server to show it in that format. You are looking at a *string representation of a date datatype*. Internally, a date is stored in a very different, format-less way.

Comment: I have 3 different date fields and all of the 3 are showing them differently

Comment: Then they are not all in a `date` datatype, some or all of them are likely `varchar` or `char`. Storing dates in a string datatype is, by the way, bad design. Always use appropriate datatypes.

Comment: If the `date` datatype doesn't have a format then why am I getting different formats (in my edit). I am converting both of them to date.

Comment: In your edit you are converting them to `varchar`, what *is* the datatype of `PublishedDate` and `ValidFromDate`? And what do they look like if you just select them, without any conversion?

Comment: They both are `nvarchar(MAX)` and without converting they look exactly the same

Answer (score 1):

If you really want the string do like this:

```
CONVERT(char(10), CONVERT(date,[date], 104),126)  AS PublishedDate
```

Convert the string to date, using the 104 format (dd.mm.yyyy), as it is your original format, then convert the date into string, using the 126 format (yyy-mm-dd)

Comment: I get the following error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a newer version of SQL Server, you may try

```
SELECT COALESCE(TRY_CAST(adate AS DATE), TRY_convert(DATE, adate, 126), TRY_convert(DATE, adate, 104)), format
FROM (
VALUES ('26.04.2017', 'dkformat') , 
('01.01.2017', 'EU format'), 
('12.12.12', 'unknown format')
) a(aDate, format)
```

But you are going down a dangerous path, when you are trying to guess what format your source is in. Been there, done that, had the t-shirt.

I still hate the 0.1% conversions that are wrong.

This solution will result in NULLs, so you can see where your conversion did not succeed.